# Magento 2 scheduled task "log_clean" stuck in running state: "Class log/cron does not exist"

Tags: magento2.3, cron

I am running M2 v 2.3.5-p1

In my cron_schedule table I have an entry as follows:

11929
log_clean
running
Class log/cron does not exist
2020-08-29 00:48:04
2020-08-29 01:00:00

As you can see it has a status of running (now been several hours since it started), and suggests Class log/cron does not exist in the messages field in the table. I do note that the directory the log files are stored in for Magento 2 changed in a recent version to var/log/ from log/.

Has anyone seen this error before in their own installations of Magento 2, or any idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have migrated database from magento 1 to magento 2 ? how did you fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove those log_clean crontab entries from core_config table